Error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append', tried pd.concat but causing error also
Getting the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append
When trying to run the following:
for idx, day_row in ecurr.iterrows():
    avlm, relm= lma(dtd, dr['fc'], dr['tc'], dr['od'])

ndf.append({'od': dr['od'], 'fc': dr['fc'], 
'tc': dr['tc'], 'r': dr['r'],
'per': alm, 'mer': ralm}, ignore_index = True)

Tried using pd.concat but that is causing a separate error:
NameError: name 'p' is not defined


Append is deprecated. Try using pd.concat([df1, df2])

This is a pretty common pitfall. Don't treat a dataframe like a list, collect your data, then create the dataframe:
import pandas as pd

data = []

# I don't know what these are so I'm putting in dummy values
av_last_month = 'somerate'
rate_end_last_mon = 'otherrate'

# Not sure how you're collecting your data here, so
# I'm just pretending rows has the correct structure
for day_row in rows:
    data.append({
        'Obs_Date': day_row['Obs_Date'], 
        'From_Currency': day_row['From_Currency'], 
        'To_Currency': day_row['To_Currency'], 
        'Rate': day_row['Rate'],
        'PE_Rate': av_last_month,  
        'Mon_End_Rate': rate_end_last_mon
    })

# create the frame here
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

